# Apk cannot be promoted from internal testing to production because of unrelated crash found in pre-launch report

Tags: android, google-play, apk, google-play-console

Google play rejected our updated apk, with the pre-launch report saying:

> Crashes and ANRs
>
> Issue 1 of 1 Detected on 1 device during testing

I'm puzzled by the rejection as the crash does not seem to relate to my app, but concerns `com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox`, as stack trace shows:

```
ANR in com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search;PID: 23476;Broadcast of Intent { act=android.accounts.LOGIN_ACCOUNTS_CHANGED flg=0x5000010 cmp=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.apps.tiktok.account.data.device.DeviceAccountsChangedReceiver_Receiver };
```

The device listed by Google is a samsung Galaxy S9 Android 8.0 (SDK 26)

What should I do next to allow publishing the updated app ?

Comment: any luck with this? I exactly the same issue

Comment: That issue was not raised by Google after an other submission. However, Google raised an other issue "Your app(s) are vulnerable to Intent Redirection" on the apk waiting for review on production channel. I was unable to publish any apk on other test channels until the apk waiting on the production channel was fixed an submitted for review.